# surface area illustration in Calculus Early Transcendentals

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

In *Calculus Early Transcendentals*, edition 6, the author uses a circular cone for a surface area problem on page 533.

The cone has a base radius $r$, slanted height $l$. A slice is made laterally, so that now there's a new cone (two cones, actually) with an upper radius $r_1$ and the same lower/base radius $r_2$. The top cone has a slanted height $l_1$, and bottom cone has a slanted height $l$.

The author says the area of the band was found by subtracting the area of the cones, $$A=\pi r_2(l_1+l)-\pi r_1 l_1=\pi[(r_2-r_1)l_1+r_2l]$$

These areas I don't understand. Shouldn't radius be squared?

Then they use similar triangles to find the area $A$. The only thing confusing me here is that $A=\pi(r_1 l+r_2 l)$ and thus $A=2\pi r l$. This suggests that $2rl=(r_1 l + r_2 l)$ which isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem that the author seamlessly switches from Fig. 2 (and the corresponding labels/symbols) to Fig. 3 - and so $l$ suddenly means a different thing. (On Fig. 2 it is the slant height of the full cone, on Fig. 3 it is the slant height of the frustum.)

Concentrating on Fig. 3, I will try to answer your questions:

> Shouldn't radius be squared?

No. The area of the lateral surface of the cone is $\pi rl$, where $r$ is the radius of the base and $l$ is the slant height (*using symbols from Fig 2 here*). This was proven on the top of the page and on the bottom of the previous page. You can also see from "dimensionality analysis": both $r$ and $l$ are *lengths* (e.g. in inches), and so $\pi rl$ has the dimension of *area* (e.g. inches squared). If $r^2$ featured in the formula, the result would have the dimension of *length cubed* (i.e. of *volume*).

Apply that to Fig. 3, where the corresponding radii are $r_1,r_2$ and the slant heights are $l_1, l_1+l$, respectively.

> This suggests that $2rl=(r_1l+r_2l)$ which isn't clear to me.

You need to again forget the symbol $r$ that was used on Fig. 2. The author *reintroduces* this symbol as $r=\frac{1}{2}(r_1+r_2)$ (the "average radius"), and then it is obviously $2r=r_1+r_2$, i.e. $2rl=(r_1l+r_2l)$.